# Yaru theme error message.....Cannot delete?

Tags: yaru

Trying to get rid of this keep getting different massages like....

```
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/Yaru' not owned by package 'yaru-theme-gnome-shell:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: directory '/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gnome-shell' contains files not owned by package yaru-theme-gnome-shell:all, cannot switch to symlink
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/yaru-theme-gnome-shell_22.04.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 new yaru-theme-gnome-shell package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

and

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/yaru-theme-gnome-shell_22.04.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thx..